# indexing with tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to implement indexing for tableview.My array contains NSManagedObjects.I have the sorted array Contactarray which contains array of sorted names.

```
    AddressBook *adBook=nil;
    adBook= [self.contactArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.lblContactName.text=[adBook valuForKey:@"name"];
```

I dont know how to access the name property of the object.

```
NSLog(@"abook%@",adBook);--->results <NSManagedObject: 0x8160630>
```

Comment: i think you want to get all contact detail in some array object or in dictionary, am i right??

Comment: is there any way to use [adbook objectAtIndexPath:indexpath] here
because i am not getting objectAtIndexPath:indexpath method here

Comment: What does contactArray contain...

Comment: sorted array of nsmanaged objects

Comment: contactArray is which type of object?? and which type of data stored in it..??

Comment: contact array is NSArray and is a collection of sorted arrays of nsmanaged objects

Comment: ok try this self.contactArray = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
NSMutableArray *arrJourneyData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:results];
    [arrJourneyData retain]; just try this dear..

Comment: after this use arrJourneyData object for array...

Comment: can you show the  .h of the AddressBook object?

Answer (score 0):

Well with the info laid down:

AddressBook *adBook=nil;
is an object and to have the value you can use the space or dot operator

as

```
cell.lblContactName.text=adBook.name;
```

OR

```
cell.lblContactName.text=[adBook name];
```